# How To Check mysql is installed in linux machine or not?

Tags: mysql, linux, installation

In my case I am trying

```
mysql --version
```

so it is showing

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.35-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

but when I am giving

```
service mysql status
```

It showing `path is not available`,please help to  find out mysql server is installed or not in particular linux machine.

Comment: server and client are two thing differents. `mysql` is the client.

Comment: The other one is `mysqld` - you can check with `which mysqld` if the binary exists.

Comment: @Ôrel thanks for replying,can u plz guid me how to find server and client both is available in linux machine or not ?

Comment: IMHO this is the role of the package manager to answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check existense of binaries:

- mysql (`which mysql`) if you need to check client existence
- mysqld (`which mysqld_safe` or `which mysqld`) if you need to check server existence

Comment: i have tried both commands which u mentioned and i got **/usr/bin/mysql** and **/usr/bin/mysqld_safe** now what next ?

Comment: that's all. If all binaries are found, then your server have mysql client and mysql server installed respectively.

Comment: but when ever giving command **service mysqld status** i got **Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  mysqld.service
mysqld.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)** so what to do ? how to start this mysql service ?

Comment: Your service name depends on the way how you installed it. `ls /etc/init.d` can help to find proper service name

Comment: After giving **ls /etc/init.d** i got
**functions  iprdump  iprinit  iprupdate  netconsole  network  pcp  pmcd  pmie  pmlogger  pmmgr  pmproxy  pmwebd  README  rhnsd  xinetd .so here how to find which is myservice.**

Comment: Oh, I see you have system.d in your server. Try this: `ls /lib/systemd/system/*.service /etc/systemd/system/*.service`

Answer (score 0):

On debian it could be done using `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -s mysql-server
```

returns

```
Package: mysql-server
Status: install ok installed
[...]
```

or

```
dpkg-query: package 'mysql-server' is not installed and no information is available
```

same for `mysql-client`

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple step if you are using Ubantu OS.
Go to search>> Ubantu software center(type in search)>>Installed(click)>>Developer Tools(click)(then it will show that mysql software is installed or not)